# Scrapy CSS Selector Issue. No issue using same selector with the selenium driver

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

This code works for me:
'''

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"""chromedriver.exe""", options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = r"""https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2023-03-23-21-tennessee.html'"""
driver.get(url)
html_source = driver.page_source
scrapy_response = TextResponse(url=driver.current_url, body=html_source, encoding='utf-8')
teams_lst_raw = scrapy_response.css('#four-factors a::attr(href)').getall()
print(teams_lst_raw)
```

'''

However, when I try to use a scrapy spider, the css selector returns a blank teams_lst. Why is this when it clearly works above?
'''

```
class CBBSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "cbb_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2023-03-23-21-tennessee.html']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        
        # Extract the HTML source
        html_source = response.body
        
        # Scrape data
        teams_lst_raw = response.css('#four-factors a::attr(href)').getall()
        teams_lst = [s[13:-14] for s in teams_lst_raw]
        print(teams_lst_raw)

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 300,
                                   'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
                                   'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
                                   'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': 18,
                                   'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 30})
process.crawl(CBBSpider)
process.start()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Because you are receiving the response before any javascript has had a chance to manipulate the html in any way. And it appears that the portion of the html that contains the element with the id `four-factors` is commented out and isn't picked up by the scrapy selectors for parsing.

This can be fixed by removing all the commented out sections from the response using regex.

For example:

```
class CBBSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "cbb_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2023-03-23-21-tennessee.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        body = response.body.decode("utf8")
        body = re.sub(r'<!--','',body)
        body = re.sub(r'-->','',body)
        response = TextResponse(response.url,encoding="utf8", body=body)
        teams_lst_raw = response.css('#four-factors a::attr(href)').getall()
        teams_lst = [s[13:-14] for s in teams_lst_raw]
        print(teams_lst)
        print(teams_lst_raw)
```

output:

```
2023-03-24 21:51:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-03-24 21:51:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-03-24 21:51:05 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-03-24 21:51:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2023-03-23-21-tennessee.html> (referer: None)
['florida-atlantic', 'tennessee']
['/cbb/schools/florida-atlantic/men/2023.html', '/cbb/schools/tennessee/men/2023.html']
2023-03-24 21:51:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```